# Solr: autoCommit what happens if Solr goes down before commiting

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

We enabled autoCommit in solrconfig.xml.

```
<autoCommit> 
  <maxDocs>5000</maxDocs>
  <maxTime>5000</maxTime>
</autoCommit>
```

Now wondering we are what happens when the Solr server does down before it reaches neither of the thresholds and there are uncommitted documents. Would those uncommited documents get commited on server restart?

Btw, we enabled autoCommit to fix

```
exceeded limit of maxWarmingSearchers=2
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume you mean Solr crashes or is killed? What happens depends on the version you are using:

- up to 3.6: docs are lost
- trunk (4.0): thanks to the [transaction log](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2700) they are not lost